# How to use Concurrency API on data frames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to parallelize the Scala Data Frames to load various tables. I have a fact table that is having around 1.7 TB of data. This is taking around 5 minutes to load. I want to concurrently load my dimension tables so that I can reduce my overall scala . I am not well versed with Concurrent API in Scala?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on Spark - the whole point of it is to parallelize processing of data beyond the scope of single machine. Essentially Spark will parallelize the load by as many tasks you'd have running in parallel - It all depends on how you set your cluster - from the question I am guessing you only use on and that you ran it in local model in which case you should at least run it with local[number of processors you have]

If I didn't make it clear you shouldn't also use any other Scala concurrency APIs

Comment: sqlContext.sql("FROM Fact_Table SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)
sqlContext.sql("FROM Dimension1 SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)
sqlContext.sql("FROM Dimension2 SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)

If i run the commands in this manner i would first execute Fact Table Select then the Dimension1 and then Dimension 2

In the above case i would like to concurrently run the statements to load Fact Table and Dimension Tables at same time rather than serially

Comment: don't collect -it sends all the data back to the executor.It seems this is an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/)  You should probably ask another question with exactly what you are trying to solve

Comment: I gave an example ideally we will be selecting into various dataframes and then be joining all the dataframes and fact table to get the final table.But my question lies how to concurrently load the data from the hive tables into dataframes in scala